# Reading custom data of next Route, Angular 11

Tags: angular

I have a router object like this

```
 const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
    {
      path: 'admin-dashboard',
      loadChildren: () => import('@sample/timesheetlibs/admin-dashboard').then((m) => m.TimesheetlibsAdminDashboardModule),
      canActivate: [UserManagementGuardService],
      data: {
        permission: 'canRouteHome'
      }
    },
    {
      path: 'user-management',
      loadChildren: () => import('@sample/timesheetlibs/user-management').then((m) => m.TimesheetlibsUserManagementModule),
      canActivate: [UserManagementGuardService],
      data: {
        permission: 'canRouteUserManagement'
      }
    },      
  ];
```

Now i want to read custom-data of next route, e.g. i am on `admin-dashboard` and i want to goto `user-management`, so in the `UserManagementGuardService`, i want to read the `data.permission` before navigation, but not sure how to read that, please help.

Comment: Inside `UserManagementGuardService` guard you want to access which data property ?

Answer (score 1):

In your `UserManagementGuardService` you can an access the data in the following way:

```
@Injectable()
class UserManagementGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(...) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean|UrlTree>|Promise<boolean|UrlTree>|boolean|UrlTree {
    const permission = route.data?.permission;
    ...
    return ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to restrict permissions to 'user-management' route. Then you need to use guard for it (as @Roman A.) described.

Alternatively, if you just need to retreive some data before resolving the route, you can use [Resolvers](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve), something like

```
{
  path: 'user-management',
  loadChildren: () => import('@sample/timesheetlibs/user-management').then((m) => m.TimesheetlibsUserManagementModule),
  canActivate: [UserManagementGuardService],
  resolve: { permission: PermissionResolver },
  data: {
    permission: 'canRouteUserManagement'
  }
}, 


@Injectable()
export class PermissionResolver implements Resolve<Permission> {
    constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<Permission> {
        return this.userService.getPermission();
    }
}

// In a UserManagementComponent you can use it as 
export class UserManagementComponent {
    permission: Permission;

    constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.permission = this.route.snapshot.data.permission as Permission;
    }
}
```